# How to call a function on node submit in drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I have created content type programmatically.. I don't want to display its node data in a block. Now I want to fetch data and save fetched data in a variable.
How can I do it ?

Or else how can I call a function on node submit ?

here is my code :

```
function default_content_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    debug($form_id);exit;

    switch($form_id) {
        case 'name_of_the_form':
            $form['#submit'][] = 'test_form_submit';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: default_content is your module name?

Comment: yeah.. its my module name

Comment: Then it's ok. Please clear your cache.

Comment: Please mark the answer it as true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) 
{
  //echo $form_id; // get the form id 
    switch($form_id)
    {
        case 'name_of_the_form': 
           $form['#submit'][] = 'test_form_submit';
           break;
    }
}

function test_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
  drupal_set_message("How are you");
}
```

Comment: what can be the value for 'name_of_the_form' ? I am using custom "content-type" to create a node not custom form.. And I tried this but its not working..

Comment: just print $form_id; there. above switch

Comment: I did but its not calling this function..

Comment: MODULE_form_alter this is not the function. MODULE replace with your module name. Its a hook. so use your module name there. eg:- your module name is 'test' then use test_form_alter is your function name

Comment: yes i know this..

Comment: You got the things currently now.

Comment: can u tell me how can i call 'test_form_submit' after submitting node ? coz i want to get the record of the currently added node in this callback..

Comment: $form_state['vlaues'] consist of the current node data

Comment: hmmm tht is fine but what if i want nid of this currently added node in this callback ?

Comment: The node hasn't actually been saved at that point, you need to implement hook_node_insert for nid.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook in a custom module on [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7). I don't really understand the other parts of the request... :/